# Confused about type declarations in Julia

Tags: performance, struct, types, julia, union-types

I'm trying to define a struct `NodeLocator`

```
@with_kw mutable struct NodeLocator{T<:Int64}
    length::T = 0
    value::Vector{T} = [0]
    maxtreelength::T = 0 end
```

And there are no problems with it.

However, I thought that my definition would be cleaner if I instead did

```
@with_kw mutable struct NodeLocator{T<:Union{Int64, Vector{Int64}}} # changed definition of T
    length::T = 0
    value::T = [0] # changed type declaration here
    maxtreelength::T = 0 end
#since
julia> Vector{Int64} <: Union{Int64,Vector{Int64}}
true
```

But in this case I get an error when constructing objects of this type:

> ERROR: MethodError: no method matching NodeLocator(::Int64,
> ::Vector{Int64}, ::Int64) Closest candidates are:   NodeLocator(::T,
> !Matched::T, ::T) where T<:Union{Int64, Vector{Int64}} at
> C:\Users\ivica.julia\packages\Parameters\MK0O4\src\Parameters.jl:526

For context, their construction includes an elementwise addition of `Int64`s to `NodeLocator.value`, and I think that what's happening is that after the first step the type of that field gets locked at `Int64` and cannot be changed to `Vector{Int64}`.

How can I parameterise the type declaration of `NodeLocator.value` without running into this error? - and does it make sense to do so? My main issue is computation time so performance is quite important for me.

Answer (score 5):

It appears that you are using the `@with_kw` macro from the Parameters package, so let's start by loading that package:

```
julia> using Parameters
```

Now, copying your definition

```
julia> @with_kw mutable struct NodeLocator{T<:Union{Int64, Vector{Int64}}}
           length::T = 0
           value::T = [0] # changed type declaration here
           maxtreelength::T = 0 end
NodeLocator
```

we can see that this works fine if we construct a struct with either all ints or all vectors

```
julia> NodeLocator(0,0,0)
NodeLocator{Int64}
  length: Int64 0
  value: Int64 0
  maxtreelength: Int64 0

julia> NodeLocator([0],[0],[0])
NodeLocator{Vector{Int64}}
  length: Array{Int64}((1,)) [0]
  value: Array{Int64}((1,)) [0]
  maxtreelength: Array{Int64}((1,)) [0]
```

but fails for mixtures, including the default you have specified (effectively, `(0, [0], 0)`)

```
julia> NodeLocator([0],[0],0)
ERROR: MethodError: no method matching NodeLocator(::Vector{Int64}, ::Vector{Int64}, ::Int64)
Closest candidates are:
  NodeLocator(::T, ::T, ::T) where T<:Union{Int64, Vector{Int64}} at ~/.julia/packages/Parameters/MK0O4/src/Parameters.jl:526
Stacktrace:
 [1] top-level scope
   @ REPL[38]:1

julia> NodeLocator() # use defaults
ERROR: MethodError: no method matching NodeLocator(::Int64, ::Vector{Int64}, ::Int64)
Closest candidates are:
  NodeLocator(::T, ::T, ::T) where T<:Union{Int64, Vector{Int64}} at ~/.julia/packages/Parameters/MK0O4/src/Parameters.jl:526
Stacktrace:
 [1] NodeLocator(; length::Int64, value::Vector{Int64}, maxtreelength::Int64)
   @ Main ~/.julia/packages/Parameters/MK0O4/src/Parameters.jl:545
 [2] NodeLocator()
   @ Main ~/.julia/packages/Parameters/MK0O4/src/Parameters.jl:545
 [3] top-level scope
   @ REPL[39]:1
```

This is because as written, you have forced each field of the struct to be *the same type `T`* which is in turn a subtype of the union.

If you really want each type to be allowed to be a `Union`, you could instead write something along the lines of:

```
julia> @with_kw mutable struct NodeLocator{T<:Int64}
           length::Union{T,Vector{T}} = 0
           value::Union{T,Vector{T}} = [0] # changed type declaration here
           maxtreelength::Union{T,Vector{T}} = 0 end

julia> NodeLocator() # use defaults
NodeLocator{Int64}
  length: Int64 0
  value: Array{Int64}((1,)) [0]
  maxtreelength: Int64 0
```

However, unless you really need the flexibility for all three fields to be unions, your *original* definition is actually much preferable. Adding `Union`s where you don't need them can only slow you down.

One thing that *would* make the code cleaner and faster would be if you could use a non-mutable struct. This is often possible even when you might not realize it at first, since an `Array` within a non-mutable `struct` is still itself mutable, so you can swap out elements within that array without needing the whole struct to be mutable. But there are certainly cases where you do indeed need the mutability -- and if you do need that, go for it.

Finally, I should note that there is not necessarily much point in constraining the numeric type to be `T<:Int64` unless that is really the only numeric type you'll ever need. You could easily make your code more general by instead writing something like `T<:Integer` or `T<:Number`, which should not generally have any adverse performance costs.